# How to use Beam's PAssert.that(foo).satisfies(bar) in Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-beam

The Beam Java API has a `PAssert` method `satisfies` which takes a function of type `SerializableFunction<Iterable<T>, Void>`

However, Java's `Void` isn't exactly the same as Scala's `Unit`, so the compiler complains if you pass something like
`PAssert.that(foo).satisfies(contents => contents.forEach(_.someListProperty.nonEmpty))`.

You can add a `asInstanceOf[Null]` at the end of the `forEach` to get rid of the compilation error, but then it throws a runtime exception saying that it cannot cast the class to null.

If you also just explicitly return null at the end of the function, the test always evaluates to true, even if the predicate was false.

How can one use this function? Or is there another way to test that each individual element of a resulting PCollection satisfies a condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This quote from your question is the core issue:

> If you also just explicitly return null at the end of the function, the test always evaluates to true, even if the predicate was false.

The idea of the function is that it should throw an exception if there is a problem, for example by using assertion methods. So your approach of adding an explicit `return null` at the end is the right way to use this directly in Scala. Adding a nice wrapper as in the other answer is good, too.

Comment: Yes. I'll choose this as the right answer because it directly addresses the issue. I was unaware that a test should throw an exception rather than just evaluate a predicate. So the approach described is correct (and a wrapper can make it easier to read) but one should use something like require() or just manually throw an exception in case the condition is not met.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue with `Kotlin` code, I think the way to solve it is the same with `Kotlin` and `Scala` :

```scala
PAssert.that(result).satisfies(assertResult)

// OR
PAssert.that(result).satisfies(assertResult(_))

// OR
PAssert.that(result).satisfies(r => assertResult(r))


private def assertResult(result: Iterable<YouClass>): Void = {
        
    // Apply your assertions.

    null
}
```

I created a method taking the result `Iterable` and returning a `Void`, then in the function, I return `null`.

In the test and `PAssert.that(foo).satisfies` method, I can invoke the `assertResult` method in a lambda function.